# MODX PHP notice: Undefined index: templates

Tags: php, indexing, undefined, modx, notice

I've made MODX template and transport.zip file from html template and when try to install it I get this notice:

PHP notice: Undefined index: templates

I'm using MODX cloud 2.2 version.

Could someone help me how to fix this notice?

Comment: Please add a peace of code ;-)

Comment: There is no php code. I just added html css and js files in modx cms and setup links. Template works well when it is installed from transport.zip file only that notice appears during instalation process. I need to fix it.

Comment: The notice specify a specific php file like : `Notice: Undefined index: test in /web/myfile.php on line 79` no?

Comment: this is what I got when install transport.zip :Console running...
...
Installing files from /paas/c2931/www/core/packages/mypackage-1.0-beta1/xPDOFileVehicle/d15241342c77cfc12b43e85cae9d044f/ to /paas/c2931/www/core/components/vapor/model/vapor
Attempting to preserve files at /paas/c2931/www/core/components/vapor/model/vapor into archive /paas/c2931/www/core/packages/mypackage-1.0-beta1/xPDOFileVehicle/d15241342c77cfc12b43e85cae9d044f.preserved.zip
PHP notice: Undefined index: templates
Successfully installed package mypackage-1.0-beta1